# Having an issue with fading in JQuery. Any ideas?

Tags: jquery, fadein, fade, fadeout

So, what I need to do is have something fading in and out repeatedly on a page until the 'reset' button is pressed (further information on that not needed).

So, I have a paragraph element on a page that is completely opaque, with id 'fail'. After a certain event is fired, this element needs to fade in and out repeatedly.

So, I do this:

```
 $("#fail").show(3000, blink);
```

With the blink function looking as follows:

```
function blink() {
    var id;
    if(divID == "lost"){
     id = "#fail"
    }else if(divID = "won"){
     id = "#win";
    }

 $(id).fadeOut().fadeIn(blink);
}
```

The if statement within is determining which paragraph element to flash. However, when I hit the first line of code above, nothing happens. Any ideas why?

Comment: what is the var `divID`

Comment: divId just holds either "lost" or "won", depending on whether the game was lost or won. At this point, divID would be "lost", thus setting the var 'id' to the correct id name, then firing the appropriate fade sequence

Comment: How are you assigning it?

Comment: Its a hangman game, so when the user runs out of tries, divID is set to "lost", and then the first line of code above comes right after

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you forgot an `=` on your second comparison. That statement is assigning `divID` to `"won"`, then evaluating it as a boolean (its not false, NULL, etc. so its always true and the `id` will always be `"#win"`). I've fixed it for you below:

```
function blink() {
    var id;
    if(divID == "lost"){
        id = "#fail"
    } else if (divID == "won") {
        id = "#win";
    }

    $(id).fadeOut().fadeIn(blink);
}
```

Now that may just be a typo, and if it is then I'll need to know what the `divID` variable is, and where it is set to help you.

### Possible Solution:

I'm not exactly sure whats going on in your application, so this may be way off-base. Having said that, why not make two blink functions, one for `#win` and one for `#fail`? Then you wouldn't need the `if` statement within the blinking function which seems to be the root of your problem.

Alternatively, you might want to try using CSS: `text-decoration: blink;`. I'm not sure if it would work for you, though. The more information you can give us about your application, the better we are able to answer ;).

Comment: divID just holds the string "lost" or "won". It is set to lost immediately before the first line of code above. So I'm setting divID to "lost", and then $("#fail").show(3000, blink);

Comment: I will try creating two different blinks, and I will tell you how that works out. If not, I'll explain what's going on a little in depth.

Comment: Ok, it stil isn't working. I will throw an edit in above and describe my application a little more.

Comment: Ok, figured it out. It was because the opacity of the paragraph elements were staying at 0, so rather than setting them to 0 I just call hide(), which causes the fade to work.

Comment: Fantastic, you should add an answer describing how you fixed it and accept it :).

Answer (score 0):

Shortened your logic up a bit...assuming that the divID is set correctly, this works:

```
$("#fail").show(3000, blink);

function blink() {
    var id;

    (divID == "lost") ? id="#fail" : id="#win";
    $(id).fadeOut().fadeIn(blink);
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uYHG5/

Answer (score 0):

The paragraph elements were failing to show because upon loading the window, I was setting them to complete opacity. I thought that since (and this may be wrong) fadeIn and Out toggled the opacity, so this wouldn't be a problem.

Regardless, rather than setting them to opaque initially, I called

```
$("p").hide();
```

So that when I call show, it is revealed and begins to toggle on and off until the game is reset. Thanks for all your tips everyone.